# How to apply a single argument function to all columns within all dataframes in a list

Tags: r

Say I have a list `dflist` which contains dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(VAR1 = letters[1:10], VAR2 = seq(1:10))
df2 <- data.frame(VAR3 = letters[11:20], VAR4 = seq(11:20))

dflist <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)
```

**In general, I want to apply a single argument function to each of the variables in each dataframe in the list**. To make the question more concrete, say I'm interested in setting the variable names to lowercase. Using a dataframe paradigm, I'd just do this:

```
colnames(df1) <- tolower(colnames(df1))
colnames(df2) <- tolower(colnames(df2))
```

However, this becomes prohibitive when I have dozens of variables in each of the 20 or 30 dataframes I'm working on, hence the shift to using lists.

I'm aware that this question stems from my fundamental misunderstanding of the `*apply` family of functions, but I've been unable to locate examples of functions applied to deeper than the first sublevel of a list. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Try `lapply(dflist, function(x) {colnames(x) <- tolower(colnames(x)); x })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @akrun suggested, the answer is simply:

```
lapply(dflist, function(x) {colnames(x) <- tolower(colnames(x)); x })
```